# Astar на C#. виснет при заходе в тупик

Tags: c#

```
public static class  A_star
{
    public const int DistanceBetweenNeighbours = 1;

    public class PathNode
    {
        public Point Pos{get;set;}
        public object ParentNode{get;set;}

        public int g{get;set;}// наименьшая оценка прибытия из startPos
        public int h{get;set;}// эвристическое приближение от данного узла к цели
        public int F()// значение оценки
        {
            return g + h;
        }
    }

    public static List<Point> FindPath(bool[,] map, Point startPos, Point goalPos)
    {

        List<PathNode> open = new List<PathNode>();
        List<PathNode> closed = new List<PathNode>();

        PathNode start = new PathNode()
        {
            Pos = startPos,
            g = 0,
            h = GetHeuristicPathLength(startPos, goalPos)
        };

        open.Add(start);
        while(open.Count > 0)
        {
            PathNode n = open.OrderBy(node => node.h).First();
            open.Remove(n);

            if (n.Pos == goalPos) return PatchBuild(n);

            if (n.h == 0)
            {
                return PatchBuild(n);
            }

            foreach (PathNode neighbourNode in GetNeighbourNode(n, goalPos, map))
            {
                int newg = n.g + 1;
                if ((closed.Contains(neighbourNode) || open.Contains(neighbourNode)) && neighbourNode.g <= newg)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (closed.Contains(neighbourNode)) closed.Remove(neighbourNode);
                    if (!open.Contains(neighbourNode)) open.Add(neighbourNode);
                }
            }

            closed.Add(n);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static List<PathNode> GetNeighbourNode(PathNode curNode, Point goalPos, bool[,] map)
    {
        List<PathNode> result = new List<PathNode>();

        Point[] neighbourPoints =
        {
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X + 1,  curNode.Pos.Y),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X - 1, curNode.Pos.Y),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X, curNode.Pos.Y + 1),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X, curNode.Pos.Y - 1),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X + 1, curNode.Pos.Y + 1),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X - 1, curNode.Pos.Y + 1),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X + 1, curNode.Pos.Y - 1),
            new Point(curNode.Pos.X - 1, curNode.Pos.Y - 1)
        };

        foreach (var point in neighbourPoints)
        {
            if (point.X < 0 || point.X >= map.GetLength(0))
                continue;
            if (point.Y < 0 || point.Y >= map.GetLength(1))
                continue;

            if (!(map[point.X, point.Y]))
                continue;

            PathNode neighbourNode = new PathNode()
            {
                Pos = point,
                ParentNode = curNode,
                g = curNode.g + DistanceBetweenNeighbours,
                h = GetHeuristicPathLength(point, goalPos)
            };

            result.Add(neighbourNode);
        }

    return result;
    }

    private static int GetHeuristicPathLength(Point from, Point to)
    {
        return Math.Abs(from.X - to.X) + Math.Abs(from.Y - to.Y);
    }
}
```

Списки `open` и `closed` постоянно растут. При обходе соседей клетки, ноды дублируются. Почему-то проверка на присутствие нода в списках не срабатывает корректно.

Comment: пробовали отлаживать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя делать проверку так, как делаете вы: объекты в C# сравниваются по умолчанию по ссылке, а ссылки-то у них всегда разные!

Продемонстрировать проблему можно вот так:

```
var start = new PathNode()
{
    Pos = startPos,
    g = 0,
    h = GetHeuristicPathLength(startPos, goalPos)
};
var start2 = new PathNode()
{
    Pos = startPos,
    g = 0,
    h = GetHeuristicPathLength(startPos, goalPos)
};
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(start, start2)); // false, т.е. с точки зрения языка это две разные ноды
```

Добавьте в класс `PathNode` переопределения методов `Equals` и `GetHashCode`. Или смените способ проверки на вхождение ноды в список.

Еще, как вариант, можно избавиться от оператора `new` в методе `GetNeighbourNode` путем создания необходимых нод заранее если ограничения это позволяют (впрочем, это плохой способ - при таких ограничениях сам алгоритм A* становится не нужен).